# How to specifiy key size in the CertCreateSelfSignCertificate function

Tags: winapi, encryption, cryptography, certificate

I am using the function [CertCreateSelfSignCertificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376039(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate a certificate.  I need to specify the key size to be `2048`.  I do not see how to provide this parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the description for the `dwFlags` argument as described in [CryptGenKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379941(v=vs.85).aspx). That should permit you to select the key length.