# How to create an X509Certificate2 that is signed by another (self-signed) certificate?

Tags: cryptography, x509certificate

I have generated my own self-signed X509Certificate2 in C#.  Now how do I create another certificate that is signed by the first in .NET?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [CertCreateSelfSignCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376039(VS.85).aspx) unmanaged API to create self-signed certificate. To be able to select the key length you should use undocumented part of the `dwFlags` parameters (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065974)).

I don't know any simple way to create a PKI with the certificates manually created like you can do this with [MakeCert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) (see my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095297/self-signed-certificates-performance-in-wcf-scenarios/4123690#4123690)). Some year ago I wrote the corresponding unmanaged code in C++, but the code is relatively long. The code consist mostly from the creating all elements of the certificate manually and the usage of [CryptSignAndEncodeCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380277(VS.85).aspx) at the end to sing the certificate with the private key of another certificate. The code examples [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads122/sourcecode/crypt/ca/517582/creatcert/CreateCert.c__.htm) and [this](http://doxygen.reactos.org/de/d51/cert_8c_source.html#l03093) can probably help you.