# Self-signed certificates performance in WCF scenarios

Tags: wcf, performance, certificate

I read that self-signed certificates suffer from performance issues (for example, [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/08/08/Creating-X509-Certificates-for-WSE-or-WCF.aspx)) but which ones exactly? I can guess this can be related to revocation checks or something but not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with [the article](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/08/08/Creating-X509-Certificates-for-WSE-or-WCF.aspx) about "performance problems" in using of certificates created by [MakeCert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx).

If no revocation information will be included in the created certificate then no performance loss can be because of revocation. Probably the only thing which is specific for using of self-signed certificate is following: you should include the self-signing certificate in the `Root` certificates store (Trusted Root Certification Authorities) or more better in the `AuthRoot` certificates store (Third-Party Root Certificate Authorities) **on all computers which will use it**. After this your self-signing certificate will be not more worth as VeriSign root certificate in the most scenarios. Of cause this way is possible only inside of one company and can be difficult used in the enterprise scenarios with a lot of independent client computers.

By the way it is possible to create a simple PKI with respect of [MakeCert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx) utility. For example you can create the self-sign root certificate of your mini CA:

```
MakeCert.exe -pe -ss MY -a sha1 -cy authority -len 4096 -e 12/31/2020 -r 
             -n "CN=My Company Root Authority,O=My Company,C=DE" MyCompany.cer
```

then you can create an additional child certificate

```
MakeCert.exe -pe -ss MY -a sha1 -len 2048 -e 12/31/2020 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
             -n "CN=My Name,O=My Company" -sky exchange
             -is MY -in "My Company Root Authority"
```

You can choose different enhanced key usage OIDs in the `eku` switch depends from the scenarios in which you want use the certificate.

To add the root certificate of your mini CA in the `AuthRoot` certificate store (Third-Party Root Certificate Authorities) we can use for example [CertMgr.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78byta0.aspx) utility

```
CertMgr.exe -add -c MyCompany.cer -s -r localMachine AuthRoot
```

You can also create and use [Certificate Revocation List File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx) if it needed for your scenario.

See [How to: Create Temporary Certificates for Use During Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx) and other [How to Articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648902.aspx) for more examples.

Comment: I'm also surprised by the performance problems in the article referenced by the OP. "These certificates have also performance problems, certain cryptographic operations may perform slowly when they are used. Certificates issued from a true Certificate Authority do not have this problem, and it is a know issue.": I'd be interested in links or more info that suggest it's true and it's a known issue indeed.

Comment: @Bruno: If you look inside of "Certificates issued from a true Certificate Authority" you will see **nothing** specific. For example you can export "VeriSign Trust Network" certificate or self-signed "Microsoft Root Authority" certificate in %TEMP%\Verisign.cer and use `certutil.exe -dump %TEMP%\Verisign.cer` or `certutil.exe -asn %TEMP%\Verisign.cer` to examine it's contain. You will find **nothing** which make it "a true Certificate Authority". Certificates must correspond to X.509 and has no hidden features. If you place a certificate in `Root` certificate store you will have the same.

Comment: @Oleg, indeed, I agree with you, it's [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/08/08/Creating-X509-Certificates-for-WSE-or-WCF.aspx) that I question. (As far as I'm aware, the only thing that makes certain big CA certificates different from others are EV certificates, which are hard-coded in browsers, but this probably doesn't have anything to with this problem, in particular because that blog entry was written in 2006 apparently, and EV certs didn't exist back then.)

Comment: @Bruno: I started my answer with my disagree with the article which you reference. How I know there are no special hard-coded certificates in IE or other browsers and in WFC.

Comment: Extended validation CA certs (or their fingerprints) are hard-coded in browsers, that's a requirement of the EV cert spec. Here's the [relevant source in Firefox (nsIdentityChecking.cpp)](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid594CB3052376BC30C1AF65EAD189675DAA2493DF.aspx) for example. (It's not exactly the cert admittedly, but it's the DN and fingerprints of which CA certs are allowed to be used to get the green bar.)

Comment: @Bruno: It is difficult for me to comment the part of Firfox code. I don't know the context, whether it is a part of non-windows code or a common code... Moreover I don't understand how the code of Firefox is connected to the question "Self-signed certificates performance in WCF scenarios"?

Comment: @Oleg, all I was saying in my first comment was that I agreed with you (I did +1 your answer) and that the article lacked data to back up its claims of performance loss. The EV cert thing is a digression, only to say that some CA certs are "special" because they've managed to get hard-coded into browsers (all those that support EV certs, including MSIE), but I don't think this specific issue has anything to do with any performance thing in the initial question indeed.

Comment: Just to clarify, the quote "These certificates have also performance problems, [...]" came from the article, not me (and that's the claim I think lacks data to back it up).

Comment: @Bruno: I understand you correct that the quoted text was from the referenced article. Probably Firefox will except some certificates also if one delete there from the Root certificate store. Some performance advantage from having the certificates in cache one will probably not really see because other things which will be done at the establishing of SSL are much more expensive as calculating of SHA1 hash and finding the corresponding certificate in the certificate store. So I (as you also) continue to suspect that self-signed certificates bring no performance loss.